# AngularJS, complex filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'd like to implement a filter that takes in up to say 3 attributes and returns result that matches all of them on the .json `input`, also known as `AND` filter.

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass the `res` (result) of my first filter as the `input` when the second filter is applied. In other words, I'd like to 'change the subject' from the original collection I iterated on to the filtered result, and keep doing that for every added filter.

Please do let me know if there is another practice for using complex filters.

Below is my code:

```
angular.module('app')
  .filter('categoryFilter', function () {
  return function (input, ctrl) {
    if(ctrl.filtersModel) {
      // 1 filter: ctrl.filtersModel > {brand: "bmw"}
      // 2 filters: ctrl.filtersModel > {brand: "bmw", speed: "medium"}
      var res = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(car){
        angular.forEach(ctrl.filtersModel, function(value, key){
          if(car[key] === value) {
            // this won't obviously work:
            res.push(car);
            // if I was able apply first filter, then save the result and use it as an input when then 2nd filter is applied, that would work
          }
        });
      });
      return res;
    }
    else {
      return input;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What I can understand from your post is that you want to cascade filters. One way to achieve that is cascading filters in your html using '|'.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, that's not what I want to achieve. I'm looking for a filter that can filter on multiple properties. The UI has say 3 dropdowns for each category I want to filter on. Selecting 1st category narrows down the result to anything with a match to the value. Selecting 2nd category further narrows down the result. Maybe I could have 3 different filters for each category, but I think it's possible to handle the logic in just one filter.

Comment: @divsingh but yes, your solution does achieve exactly the same result

Comment: exactly. since you have the check on ctrl.filtersModel to return the input when no filter is supplied, all you need to have is 3 different filters and cascade them. This also gives you modularity and flexibility.